# Read Content-Disposition: form-data; name="json" using .net core + AWS

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, content-type

I have integrated my .net-core MVC application with a third-party system for a callback hit.
When i host the above application in Azure my API works as expected but when I host it AWS elastic beanstalk it does not work.
In Azure input for API comes as an object but in AWS it case as below
Below is the request I am receiving from third-party to my call back API.

```
------------------------------e2bdba1d3cf0
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="json"

{"Transaction":{"Guid":"[Fax GUID]","To":"14154847140","From":"14154847140","IsInbound":false,"IsDraft":false,"TypeCode":"F","StatusCode":"S","ErrorCode":null,"CreatedAt":"1505933982","UpdatedAt":"1505934022","Uri":"\/v1\/Accounts\/[Your Account GUID]\/Transmissions\/[Fax GUID]","NumPagesBilled":1}}
------------------------------e2bdba1d3cf0--
```

My API Code

```
  [HttpPost]
        [Route("CallBack")]
        public string CallBack()
        {
            try
            {
                eSignService eSignService = new eSignService();
                dynamic json = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Request.Body).ReadToEndAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                if (json != null)
                {
                    //logic to save the file
                }
                else
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("No Data Found");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("Error : " + ex);
            }
            string result = "Hello API Event Received";
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: EC2 or Azure will make no difference to your application code - what is the actual problem?

Comment: I am trying to read the data from body using the below line

dynamic json = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Request.Body).ReadToEndAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

and then De-Serialize it into a JSON object 

JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(HttpContext.Session.GetString(json)

where i am getting the below error

Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: The best overloaded method match for 'string.this[int]' has some invalid arguments
at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , String )

Comment: in azure the output of the below line is coming as object but in AWS its coming as string
dynamic json = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Request.Body).ReadToEndAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

Comment: `dynamic json` - well yes it is, you're specifying it to have a `dynamic` type

Comment: do `string json` - there is no reason for it to need to be dynamic

Comment: according to the third-party call back the request should be an object thats y i have assigned it to dynamic. Its working as expected when hosted as azure webapp.
In AWS Elastic Beanstalk the request is coming as string:

Comment: ------------------------------e2bdba1d3cf0
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="json"

{"Transaction":{"Guid":"[Fax GUID]","To":"14154847140","From":"14154847140","IsInbound":false,"IsDraft":false,"TypeCode":"F","StatusCode":"S","ErrorCode":null,"CreatedAt":"1505933982","UpdatedAt":"1505934022","Uri":"\/v1\/Accounts\/[Your Account GUID]\/Transmissions\/[Fax GUID]","NumPagesBilled":1}}
------------------------------e2bdba1d3cf0--

Now my question is how do i get above request into an object the way its working in Azure?